# How to get array of keys of multidimensional array like this

Tags: php

I have a multidimensional array

```
$array = ['a'=>'one','b'=>['two','three'],'c'=>['four','five','six']];
```

I want an array of keys according to the length(count) of the value(array) like this

```
$array_keys = ['a','b','b','c','c','c'];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to glue arrays, and [array_fill()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) should do the trick:

```
$result = [];
foreach($array as $k=>$arr) 
   $result = array_merge($result, array_fill(0,count($arr),$k));
```

[**Live demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/47b5ee8cd6f4cbf1d2c32a7bbae57fe82611bb4a)

Comment: aw yeah this is much cleaner! +1

Comment: Another one liner: `array_push($result, ...array_fill(0,count($arr),$k));` _--just saying :)_

Comment: @Thamilan Absolutely; didn't think of that one. I love he spread operator.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a mix of foreach, and for:

```
foreach ($array as $k => $v)
{
    for ($i = 1; $i <= count($v); $i++)
    {
        $keys[] = $k
    }
}
```

this will loop through, count  the length of the array and foreach item, add it to the keys array.

Comment: i think it should be `$i=1`